# Can Someone Explain the Set $\{ ∈ ℝ^ ∣ d(x,0) = 1\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand this set. I understand most of the individual parts such as $∈$ means "an element of", $ℝ$ is all real numbers, and $d(x,0) = 1$ is the distance from $x$ to $0$, as in absolute value.

I don't understand what $x$ means in this situation though. Is it considered a variable? Is it multiple values?

I also don't understand what the actual elements of the set are. Is the value of $x$ and element in the set? Also, are there any other numbers with an absolute value of $1$ other than $1$ and $-1$? If not, are those the only possible values for $x$?

In this situation, $N$ is a number of dimensions, but I don't understand how that relates to real numbers, nor what real numbers to any power would be.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you working with here? you have defined a subset of $R^n$ that satisfies some condition $d(x,0) = 1$... what is 'distance' here? how is this distance defined?

Answer (score 4):

$x$ is just a name. Translated into English, the set

$$\{x \in \Bbb R^n | d(x,0) = 1 \}$$

would read "all elements of the set $\Bbb R^n$, such that the distance between that element and $0$ is $1$." (Presumably $0$ here denotes the "origin," so to speak, if you were considering graphing in $\Bbb R^n$.) This is essentially the $n$-dimensional unit sphere - for example, in $\Bbb R^2$, this set denotes all points on the circle of radius $1$.

The name $x$ is just a shorthand, it doesn't mean anything other than giving elements of $\Bbb R^n$ some sort of name in the setbuilder notation above.

$\Bbb R^n$, to answer your other question, is the $n$-dimensional analogoue of the real number line. For example, $n=2$ gives you the $xy$-plane; $n=3$ gives you typical $3D$ Cartesian space; and so on.

If you're at all familiar with the notion of Cartesian product, $\Bbb R^n$ can also be expressed as

$$\mathbb{R}^n = \underbrace{\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times ... \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}}_{\text{n times}}$$

and thus that allows us to express elements of $\Bbb R^n$ by $n$-tuples. For example, for $n=2$, we would have our typical $(x,y)$ ordered pairs from the $xy$-plane. Generally then, for the $n$-dimensional case, you could express elements of $\Bbb R^n$ by ordered $n$-tuples $(x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n)$, where $x_k$ is a real number for all $k$.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that $\Bbb R^n$ is the cartesian product $$\underbrace{\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\times...\times\Bbb R}_{\text{n times}}$$ consisting of $n-$tuples with real entries.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, no idea how I overlooked elaborating on it. ^_^

Comment: Why does $d(x,0)$ refer to the unit sphere? I can't see a definition for $d(x,0)$ and more so if the set is indeed a metric space, inner produce space, normed space. It seems you have inferred it's in reference to the Euclidean distance which is defined via an induced norm (via the Euclidean Inner Product Space). 

If that turns out to be correct, your solution is spot on. If not, this could potentially be misleading.

Answer (score 2):

The notation $d(x,0)=1$ seems to indicate that this is a problem in a general metric space. This is not necessarily the absolute value, as there can be more abstract metrics. This set is the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with respect to this metric.

Comment: There is a lot of unknowns in the question as presented. I'm assuming that it's a distance formed from an induced norm of an inner product space, but we don't know for sure (unless I've missed something of course).